# What's the difference between SCID and SCID vs PC?

Tags: database, scid

I've got two files installed on my site from SCID & SCID vs PC - Scid vs PC-4.16.x64 & Scid-4.6.2. How are they different ? Or are they just the same ? Which one should I delete if it is a replica?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Shane's Chess Information Database** (SCID) is a powerful Chess Toolkit, with which one can create huge databases, run chess engines, and play casual games against the computer or online with the Free Internet Chess Server. It was originally written by Shane Hudson , and has received strong contribution from Pascal Georges and others.
>
> **Scid vs. PC** began with bug-fixes for the computer-versus-player features of Scid (hence the name), but has evolved into a solid alternative with many new features and interfaces. The project is authored by Stevenaaus and numerous contributors.

So they are not the same. *Scid vs. PC* is a *SCID* variant.

Comment: Are both useful or is one better.  Especially better for a given purpose?

Answer (score 2):

If you are first-time user, difference is negligable. One is a fork of another. Both using Tcl/Tk toolkit to implement interfaces. Both support UCI/XBoard engine interfaces. I am personally more inclined to the second purely our of historical differences. There was a moment when scidvspc had more novelty, but now basically all of the functions are the same.

Answer (score -1):

I personally use SCID over SCID VS PC just because you can store more games on SCID(Unlimited) than SCID VS PC(10 Games) on a single database.

Comment: Really?! That seems improbable?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you can store an unlimited amount of games on SCIDvsPC as well- will check now.

EDIT: Just made a database with 12 games in SCID vs PC, so.... yeah this is inaccurate.